# How is AlexNet 8 layers deep?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to understand why [for example on MatLab page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/alexnet.html) AlexNet is described as:

> AlexNet is a convolutional neural network that is 8 layers deep.

After using analyzeNetwork() to check the architecture, there is clearly 25 layers.

How 25 layers are related to 8 layers deep? What's the difference between those two values?
I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB documentation is probably not clear enough. I should maybe talk about blocks (Personally I prefer this word). If you look at the figure: [image]

Many "layers" have at the end a number that represents the block in which it is contained.

The term layer is often not clear, there are people who consider that a convolution + activation + batch norm is a layer. There is no consensus. In the case of MATLAB it is only counting the layers that have weights.

Comment: Thank you, the last part helped me a lot. I found, that we actually don't count the activation functions and the max/average pooling layers, as they have no parameters. Also, I struggled with GoogLeNet architecture, but I believe that it's because of inception layers, so when there's more than one conv layer on the same level, all of them all counted as one.